# NodeJs Mongoose + Mongo, connecting to localhost

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I just updated to node 0.5.10 from 0.4.11 and my version of mongoose from 2.0.2 to 2.3.13 however I can no longer connect to localhost. My code has not changed at all, and I can still connect to my production server on mongolab. I can connect to my local db using a gui (MongoHub) just going through localhost. I am now running out of ideas. I've tried variations on the following connection strings which both should work in my option.

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb
mongodb://localhost/mydb
```

I have even created a very basic single app to just save something to my localhost but to no avail. Ideas are very welcome!

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/SomeDb');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Posts = new Schema({
  name : String,
});
mongoose.model('Post', Posts);

function createNewPost(){
    var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
    var post = new Post({name:'new name'});
    post.save(function(err){
      console.log("saving");
        if(!err){
            console.log('Post saved.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Obvious, but did you reinstall all of the modules/drivers?

Comment: thanks, yep including new mongodb.

Comment: Why are you on 0.5.10? 0.6 (stable) is already out.

Comment: Part of the reason was I was expecting everything to break upgrading node so I wanted to do it in 2 steps 0.4.11 -> 0.5.10 then 0.5.10 -> 0.6.x. I am now running 0.6.2 successfully.

Comment: what does ip address does 'localhost' resolve to on your system?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After debugging using the mongodb native I found that 127.0.0.1 works. I have not idea but I am back up and running.

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb
```